# sum of number using private mode of inheritance in c++

Tags: c++

How to make this type of program. How to do that can someone say as soon as possible a simple program will also work like sum of two number with private mode of inheritance.

[image]

output need to be look like this

I make this program with public mode of inheritance and I want this program in private mode of inheritance.

I need to use `class child : private base1, private base2`

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base1
{
    public:
    int a;
    void geta()
    {
        cout<<"enter value of a: "; 
        cin>>a;
    }
};
class base2
{
    public:
    int b;
    void getb()
    {
        cout<<"enter value of b: ";
        cin>>b;
    }
};
class child : public base1, public base2
{
    public:
    void sum()
    {
        cout<<"Sum of a and b is: "<<a + b;
    }
};

int main()
{
     child c;
     c.geta();
     c.getb();
     c.sum();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but post text as text. You should also show the program  _with public mode of inheritance_ you have written, otherwise we can't really help you much. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: Thank you for showing your code, but it's stilly pretty unclear what you're asking. You need to elaborate.

Comment: ok. I make this program with the public scope of inheritance . I want simlar program with inheritance of base 1 and base 2 class is need to be private

Comment: Then you need to provide a public function that calls the private `geta` and `getb` methods for the caller.

Comment: You mean `class child : private base1, private base2`?

Comment: yes @Jabberwocky

Comment: i will try @Botje

Comment: @ADARSHBHARDWAJ you should make that clear in the question. You can [edit] it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
...
class child : private base1, private base2
{
public:
  void sum()
  {
    cout << "Sum of a and b is: " << a + b;
  }

  void getaandb()
  {
    geta();
    getb();
  }
};

int main()
{
  child c;
  c.getaandb();
  c.sum();
  return 0;
}
```